# How to only get text or numbers from element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to only get text from the element and then only to get numbers from that element.

```
global textelement
    textelement = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='text-nowrap text-truncate']")))).text
```

The text I get looks something like this

```
U(4) Leiknir
```

I want one variable to only contain text from the element and one variable to only contain numbers from that text so the output looks like this :

Text only

```
U Leiknir
```

and

Numbers only

```
4
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by using regex.

`Import re`

```
textelement ="U(4) Leiknir"
number=re.findall(r'\d+', textelement)[0]
print(number)
chars = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", textelement))
print(chars)
```

**output:**

```
4
U Leiknir
```

**Update:**

```
textelement ="U(3.45) Leiknir"
number=re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', textelement)[0]
print(number)
chars = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", textelement))
print(chars)
```

Comment: Thank you it's working aswell, but now I'm having a problem when numbers are decimal so instead of printing 3.54 it prints out 3,5,4 is there a command to somehow combine them and put . there it was at the begining

Comment: @ElBob, Just change the `regex` criteria. Check my updated answer. This will work with both number and float.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can do this by using regex and filter function like this.

```
import re
def filter_str(s):
    res_num = [int(match) for match in re.findall(r"\d+", s)]
    res_str = "".join(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), s))
    
    return res_num, res_str

s = "U(4) Leiknir"
a, b = filter_str(s)
print("Numbers: ", a , "\nStr: ", b)
```

Output:

```
Numbers:  [4] 
Str:  U() Leiknir
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working.  Is it possible to print number like 4.7 so instead of printing it like [4,7] it prints out [4.7]?